# Php QB Desktop: getting error Error message received from application via getLastError():

Tags: php, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I am adding payment received. Logs say request is "q" but never processed. No exact error.

```
public function _loginSuccess($requestID, $user, $hook, &$err, $hook_data, $callback_config){
    $Queue = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue($this->DSN);
    $Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_ADD_RECEIVEPAYMENT, 100);
    return true;
}

public function _addReceivePaymentRequest($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale){
        $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <?qbxml version="2.1"?>
            <QBXML>
            <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
            <ReceivePaymentAddRq requestID="'.$requestID.'">
                <ReceivePaymentAdd>
                    <CustomerRef>
                        <FullName>John Miller</FullName>
                    </CustomerRef>
                    <TxnDate>2016-10-13</TxnDate>
                    <RefNumber>18215417</RefNumber>
                    <TotalAmount>10.2</TotalAmount>
                    <PaymentMethodRef>
                        <FullName>Visa</FullName>
                    </PaymentMethodRef>
                    <AppliedToTxnAdd>
                        <TxnID>42B-4517541</TxnID>
                        <PaymentAmount>10.2</PaymentAmount>
                    </AppliedToTxnAdd>
                </ReceivePaymentAdd>
            </ReceivePaymentAddRq>
            </QBXMLMsgsRq>
            </QBXML>';

    return $xml;
}

public function _catchallErrors($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $xml, $errnum, $errmsg){
    return true;
}
```

QB Desktop showing: Error message received from application via getLastError():
DB table "quickbooks_queue" field "qb_status" has "q" in it.

Comment: Please POST YOUR LOGS and POST THE REST OF THE RELEVANT CODE.

Comment: Please check logs table screenshot http://nimb.ws/fRUCiy

FYI, sometimes it runs smooth.

Comment: And where are your Web Connector logs, in VERBOSE mode?

Comment: And the rest of your code?

Comment: Are you talking about these logs?
[link](http://nimb.ws/J0loY1)

I am sorry i am new to QB Desktop integration.

Comment: No, I'm talking about the logs that show up when you hit the [View Log] button in the Web Connector. Do a Google search.

Comment: QB Desktop logs: Version:
PHP QuickBooks SOAP Server v3.0 at /qb_syncer/quickbooks/qbwc

Message:
: 

Description:
Error message received from application via getLastError(): :

Comment: Put the Web Connector in VERBOSE mode. Run it. Click the VIEW LOG button in the Web Connector. You should see like 10,000 lines of text.